# Java retrieve alternative Ldap Attribute names

Tags: java, attributes, ldap, jndi

**The situation:**

I'm actually reading contact information from an Ldap source within a Java application. The found SearchResult contains all values I want, no trouble with that. 
Once the SearchResult is available, I need to read its attributes - which attributes to read, is specified by the user in a config file.

**The problem, explained on an example:**

A user specifies to read the property 'stateOrProvinceName'. The Ldap handles this as 'st'. The returned Searchresult will contain a key=>value pair with 'st' as key. If I look up 'stateOrProvinceName' this will of cource not be found. I want that 'st' key - but I do not want to manually code a mappnig of alternative Ldap-Field names. The relevant code part:

```
Attributes ldapAttributes = foundContact.getAttributes();
Attribute wantedAttribute = ldapAttributes.get(ldapFieldName);
```

*Explanation: 'foundContact' is the SearchResult, I store its Attributes in 'ldapAttributes'. The 'ldapFieldName' is the name, the user specified in the config file (like 'stateOrProvinceName'), I try to get this attribute and store it in 'wantedAttribute'. If 'stateOrProvinceName' is not contained, 'wantedAttribute' is of course null. But since 'st' exists, I do not want this to be null ;)*

**The question:**

is there some 'easy' way to retrieve a list of all alternative names, given one name of an attribute?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rfc'ed approach for that is to locate the attribute definition in your entry's subschemaSubentry referenced schema definition. (p32 in [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#page-32))

E.g. OpenLDAP stores this information in cn=Subschema. Unfortunately this entry uses the attribute definition format which you first have to parse by yourself:

```
attributetype ( 2.5.4.8 
    NAME ( 'st' 'stateOrProvinceName' ) 
    DESC 'RFC2256: state or province which this object resides in' 
    SUP name )
```

Iirc/maybe UnboundID's LDAP SDK has now a parser for this purspose.